# What is a proper way of switching the servers and VMs off and on for power outage?

Tags: linux, admin, shutdown

my organisation have two physical servers and some VMs. Currently when there is a pre-scheduled power outage, I use a script I wrote to loop through all VMs scheduling a shutdown command to all VMs and the servers. For example,

```
ssh root@${VMS[$i]} 'echo "shutdown -h now" | at 05:00am Mar 31'
```

Then I restart the machines when I am back to the office in the morning.

Is this the appropriate way of doing the auto shutdown? Do you do it differently? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: This should be asked at serverfault.com. Us programmers don't know this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, the shutdown command can take a time directly itself, you don't need to use at for that (see http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ushutdow.htm).

Beyond that, though, I don't see anything wrong with this approach, provided that your environment can tolerate those servers being offline potentially longer than necessary (i.e. if a power outage lasts from 9-10 pm, but you don't start them back up until 8 am the next morning, that's 10 hours longer that they were off than they really needed to be), which your description seems to suggest is the case. In this environment, I don't think I would do anything differently, beyond also scheduling the host computer to shutdown a couple of minutes after the VMs are scheduled to do so.